# Promise.all Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: #<Promise> is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

So I have 2 APIs I need to hit, and wait on both responses to come back before I dispatch my action.

I'm using `Promise.all` however running into the following error:

> index.js:51 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: # is not iterable
>       at Function.all ()

```
const fetchPrices = () => Promise.resolve(getPrices());
const fetchSupplies = () => Promise.resolve(getSupply());
const fetchAll = () => Promise.all(fetchPrices(), fetchSupplies()).then((resultsArray) => {
  return resultsArray;
});

// GET coins from coinmarketcap Pro API v1.
export const startGetPrices = () => dispatch => fetchAll().then((res) => {
  console.log('res', res);
  //...
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all` accepts an *array* of `Promises`, not `Promises` listed after one another in the parameter list. Change to:

```
const fetchAll = () => Promise.all([
  fetchPrices(),
  fetchSupplies()
]);
```

Note that

```
.then((resultsArray) => {
  return resultsArray;
});
```

is superfluous; the existing `Promise` resolves to an array of results, so calling `.then` on it to chain *another* `Promise` onto it that takes that array of results and resolves to that array doesn't do anything useful; you can leave it off entirely.

Also, there's no need to use `Promise.resolve` - I don't know what `getPrices` and `getSupply` return, but if you pass non-Promises into `Promise.all`, no error will be thrown, the resulting array will simply include those values. (If Promises are returned, then the `Promise.all` will resolve when all such Promises have resolved.) So, you could do:

```
const fetchAll = () => Promise.all([
  getPrices(),
  getSupply()
]);
```

(of course, if both `getPrices` and `getSupply` return non-Promises, then there's no need for `Promise.all` in the first place)